# How to make a single $format element required in PHP

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm currently trying myself at turning an 'alias' field from optional to required. But every approach results in an blank, broken page.

My first idea was to simply add an `->setRequired(true)` below alias' $this but that broke the page.
I then tried to detach it by

```
$format = [alias] = (new FormField();
->setName('alias')
            ->setLabel(
                $this->getFieldLabel('alias')
            )
)
```

I then tried this:

```
       if ($field === 'alias') {
                if ($this->country->need_zip_code) {
                    $formField->setRequired(true);
                }
            }
```

Inspired by other parts of the code in the same file but I quickly figured out that without knowing the syntax, nor anything about the underlying workings, I won't be able to modify it by myself.

```
public function getFormat()
{
    $fields = AddressFormat::getOrderedAddressFields(
        $this->country->id,
        true,
        true
    );
    $required = array_flip(AddressFormat::getFieldsRequired());

    $format = [
        'id_address'  => (new FormField)
            ->setName('id_address')
            ->setType('hidden'),
        'id_customer' => (new FormField)
            ->setName('id_customer')
            ->setType('hidden'),
        'back' => (new FormField)
            ->setName('back')
            ->setType('hidden'),
        'token'       => (new FormField)
            ->setName('token')
            ->setType('hidden'),
        'alias'       => (new FormField)
            ->setName('alias')
            ->setLabel(
                $this->getFieldLabel('alias')
            )
    ];
```

I expected the alias field to be marked as required but instead it broke the page.

Comment: When you say it broke the page, what error did you get?

Comment: @RobFos looks like syntax error. No idea, how this could be transformed into a good question.

Comment: Apparently you are modifying core files, which all will be lost during upgrade. What is your goal?

Comment: @Abid Aroui I can just put them into the overrides folder to not lose them.@RobFos it's literally just a white page.

Comment: the alias field for adresses is already required by default in prestashop. Just look at the `$definition` of the Adress Class, not sure why you are trying to set an already required field to required? Also the `getFormat` method you posted is located in CustomerAdressFormater, this is not the place to set fields to required.